# Magento 2: Catalog Rule Collection -> filter by store

Tags: magento2, catalog-price-rules, catalog-rules

I have the following block of code that gets all active catalog rules:

```
$catalog_rule_collection = $objectManager
                         ->create('\Magento\CatalogRule\Model\RuleFactory')
                         ->create()
                         ->getCollection()
                         ->addFieldToFilter('simple_action', 'by_percent')
                         ->addIsActiveFilter(1);
```

`->addFieldToFilter('simple_action', 'by_percent')` filters results to catalog rules with a percentage discount.

`->addIsActiveFilter(1)` filters results to only activated catalog rules.

This simply retrieves table data from the `catalogrule` table. The following SQL query would achieve the same result:

```
SELECT discount_amount
FROM catalogrule
WHERE simple_action = 'by_percent' AND is_active = 1
```

How do I filter results by store-ID-specific catalog rules? So if a catalog rule affects store 1 but not store 2, how can I express the following:

`->addStoreFilter(1) //pseudocode`

Consider that the `catalogrule` table does not have a `store` column, nor is the store ID specified in the `conditions_serialized` or `actions_serialized` tables. Yet in Magento 2, catalog rules can be set uniquely by store.

Comment: Magento default allows catalog price rule settings per website level only. `website_ids` attribute

Comment: @PЯINCƏ I see that that `catalogrule` table's first column is `rule_id` which joins with the `catalogrule_website` table. That table has the column for `website_id`. So you're very close to answering my question.

Now for example; `\Magento\CatalogRule\Model\RuleFactory` gets the `catalogrule` table. All I need to know now is the namespace which references the `catalogrule_website` table.

Comment: @PЯINCƏ Nevermind, I found the solution. Posting now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to `JOIN` the `catalogrule` table to the `catalogrule_website` table. The two tables share a `rule_id` column, and then the `catalogrule_website` table has a `website_id` column which specifies which website id (which == store id) the catalog rule applies to.

Via Magento this would be accomplished simply by adding `->addWebsiteFilter($store_id)`.

Here is the entirety of my code for anybody who is interested.

```
$store_id = 1;
$product_id = 101;

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$catalog_rule_collection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\CatalogRule\Model\RuleFactory')
                                         ->create()
                                         ->getCollection()
                                         ->addFieldToFilter('simple_action', 'by_percent')
                                         ->addWebsiteFilter($store_id)
                                         ->addIsActiveFilter(1);

if (!empty($catalog_rule_collection)) {
    foreach ($catalog_rule_collection as $catalog_rule) {
        $sale_applicable_product_ids = $catalog_rule->getMatchingProductIds();
        if (!empty($sale_applicable_product_ids)) {
            if (array_key_exists($product_id, $sale_applicable_product_ids)) {
                $discount_amount = $catalog_rule->getData('discount_amount');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Working great.This is what i am looking for